# Can't use Windows Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm making a simple application, but when I add a Windows Form I get an error. I tried to modify ".NET desktop development" and add "C++/CLI support" but it wont work.

[image: My visual studio]

<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: If your question is about C++/CLI, please tag it. C++ has no notion of windows forms.

Comment: you give us no information at all that we can use to help you. Are you using Winforms or not ? And if yes with c# then ? What error did you get ? How do you add a form ? This is like calling a workshop saying my car does not work but you may not see it or touch it, please fix it now

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add a Winform in a Native C++ app. What you want to do is to add a new dialog to the project.

Open the Solution Explorer 
Scroll down to Resource Files Right click
Select Add ==> Resource. 
Select Dialog and then click New.

See the image below.
[image]